# MATLAB drop observations from a timetable not contained in another timetable

Tags: matlab, timetable, drop

I have two timetables, each of them have 4 columns, where the first 2 columns are of my particular interest. The first column is a date and the second is an hour.

[image]

How can I know which observations (by date an hour) are in the timetable 1 but not in the timetable 2 and, therefore, drop those observations from my timetable 1?

So for example, just by looking I realized that timetable1 included the day 25/05/2015 with hours 1 and 2, but the timetable 2 did not include them, therefore I would like to drop those observations from timetable 1.

I tried using the command `groups_timetable1 = findgroups(timetable1.Date,timetable1.Hour);`but unfortunately this command does not tell you a lot how to distinguish between observations.

Thank you!

Comment: calculate the duration between each entry of one table and all entries in the other and see if there exists an entry to which the duration is smaller than your threshold

Comment: Thank @max, but could you please develop more your idea? How can I calculate the duration of a date of type 'datetime'? what do you mean by threshold? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, I could. Could you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The threshold is just the amount of time that you want to allow for time still to be considered as equal. 1 second, 1 minute, ...

Comment: What are the datatypes in your table? I imagine `timetable1.Date` is datetime, but what about `timetable1.Hour` ?

Comment: timetable1.Hour is a double

Answer (score 1):

call `ismember` to find one set of data in another.
to find multiple records as a group in another composite records, you call `ismember(..., 'rows')`.

for example

```
baseline=[
  100, 2.1
  200, 7.5
  120, 11.0
];
isin=ismember(baseline,[200, 7.5],'rows');
pos=find(isin)
```

if you have time date strings or `datetime` objects, please convert those to numerical values, such as by calling `datenum` or `posixtime` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `timetable` method [`innerjoin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/innerjoin.html) to do this. Like so:

```
% Fabricate some data
dates1 = datetime(2015, 5, ones(10,1));
hours1 = (1:10)';
timetable1 = timetable(dates1(:), hours1, rand(10,1), rand(10,1), ...
    'VariableNames', {'Hour', 'Price', 'Volume'});
% Subselect a few rows for timetable2
timetable2 = timetable1([1:3, 6:10],:);

% Use innerjoin to pick rows where Time & Hour intersect:
innerjoin(timetable1, timetable2, 'Keys', {'Time', 'Hour'})
```

By default, the result of `innerjoin` contains the table variables from both input tables - that may or may not be what you want.